Getting error "Cannot Check Device Activation Status" while trying to get access token from PRODA
I want to connect with PRODA services, and I have successfully Activate the device using vb.net or using SOAPUI, but when I am going to get access token, i am getting the following error "Cannot Check Device Activation Status", this error not mentioned in the documentation.
Someone help me to solve this issue.
Note: The same response I am getting using example code that are provided with documentation.
This is my request
Dim output As String = "client_id=" & clientId &
            "&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=" & assertion
        Return output

and this is my assertion
Dim payload = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        payload.Add("sub", deviceName) ' this is the name of the device
        payload.Add("iss", orgRA) ' this is the PRODA Organisation RA number
        payload.Add("aud", "http://proda.humanservices.gov.au") ' this represents who will receive the JWT, PRODA.
        payload.Add("token.aud", tokenAudience) ' this will be the audience of the generated access token, in thiscase medicare online
        payload.Add("exp", getCurrentUnixTimestamp(expiresInSeconds)) ' this is current timestamp + 600 seconds (10 minutes), the expiry time of this JWT
        payload.Add("iat", getCurrentUnixTimestamp) ' this is the current time, the time this JWT was created (issued at)

        ' Set up extra headers
        Dim extraHeaders = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        extraHeaders.Add("kid", deviceName) ' this is the name of the device, the key id (kid) of the key used to sign this JWT


        ' create the signed JWT assertion
        Dim token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, rsaCsp, Jose.JwsAlgorithm.RS256, extraHeaders)

